# Is it possible to use PostgreSQL Trigram index pg_trgm directly?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, trigram

I want to use my own function to produce trigram vector, for both indexing and querying, is it possible?

How it usually works:

```
indexing : text  => pg_text_to_trigram_vector => submit vector to index
querying : query => pg_text_to_trigram_vector => query using vector
```

I would like to bypass the `pg_text_to_trigram_vector` step and submit my own differently generated trigram vector to index and query directly

```
indexing : my-own-trigram-vector => submit my-vector to index
querying : my-own-trigram-vector => query using my-vector
```

or maybe I can define my own function and PostgreSQL will use it to generate trigram vector, that also would 
be ok

```
indexing : text  => my-own-function => submit my-vector to index
querying : query => my-own-function => query using my-vector
```

Is that possible?

**Example:**

I'd like to submit 3 vectors to index

```
['abc', 'cbd', 'def']
['abc']
['sdd', 'dd3', '5gd', 'd4d']
```

And then query it with other vector

```
['abc', 'cbd']
```

Basically it's same as `pg_trgm` but bypassing the trigram generation step.

Comment: Because `pg_trgm` can enhance *`LIKE`, `ILIKE`, `~` and `~*` queries* too, I don't think it will ever be possible (with that exact module).

Comment: Maybe you could use an expression index on some `text[]` value (GIN supports the `&&`, `<@` and `@>` operators for arrays f.ex.) -- but this depends on your actual use-case.

Comment: @pozs thanks, I added an example.

Comment: please add your wanted output too (with possibly the logic behind it). `pg_trgm` does very different things for f.ex. `LIKE` and for its own *similarity match* (which is based on thresholds).

Comment: Hmm, why is it different? Postgres does `column % 'my-text'` I want to do `column % ['abc', 'cbd']`. It should work the same, just bypassing the text-to-trigram step and supplying trigram explicitly.